# Android Studio imports whole location folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I exported my eclipse project as suggested [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects).

Then I got some `gradle-files` in my /home/mike/ - folder. I do not know why he puts the files into /home/mike and not into workspace under the related project.. but it is not possible to change the destination of the gradle file when exporting the project from eclipse................

However android studio annoys me extremely... (Yeah I know I should pretend I am a computer with no emotions... I see incoming downvotes because I act like a human)

When I try to import the `gradle.build` via e.g. `File -> Import Settings` choosing the build.gradle from eclipse export Android Studio gives me following output:

[image]

So now im glad Android Studio, however, imported/or showing my whole home-folder of my user mike. Because I can not manage my home folder from the windows explorer, Android Studio imports it and helps me...... I get sick.

So I am not familiar with gradle, sure I am doing something wrong but what?

Why does he import my whole folder where the gradle.build file of my porject is located? Why he just do not import the Project??

Answer (score 1):

> I exported my eclipse project

Instead of exporting eclipse project you should have **imported** it directly by android studio, especially documentation clearly advices going that way:

> Importing the Eclipse project directly into Studio. **This is the
>   preferred approach, and has numerous advantages**

Comment: You are right. I totally missed that.. I thought because my `Eclispe Project` is not using `gradle` I need to export it first as `gradle-project`.. I will try the solution and give some feedback. Anyway do you know how I can remove my showed home-folder in eclipse? Or is it really imported?